# Javascript (nodejs) templating with Plates

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, templates

I want to build my html code on server side.

To do this I'm using Plates which is a templating javascript library.
I tried to get this code working but it just don't modifies the original html template code...

```
var Plates = require("plates")

var html    = "<h1>Template test with plates</h1>"
            + "<p my-content>This should be erased...</p>";

var data = { 'my-content': "It is: "+new Date() };

console.log(Plates.bind(html, data));
```

This should output the date instead of the default string but it doesn't...

I also tried with the mapper but it didn't succeed nether:

```
var Plates = require("plates")

var html    = "<h1>Template test with transparency</h1>"
            + "<p my-content>This should be erased...</p>";

var data = { 'content': "It is: -> "+new Date() };

var map = Plates.Map();
map.where('my-content').use('content');

console.log(Plates.bind(html, data, map));
```

The only code sample I got working is as follow:

```
var Plates = require("plates")

var html    = "<h1>Template test with transparency</h1>"
            + "<p my-content='changeable'>This should be erased...</p>";

var data = { 'content': "It is: -> "+new Date() };

var map = Plates.Map();
map.where('my-content').is("changeable").use('content');

console.log(Plates.bind(html, data, map));
```

But I don't need that `my-content='changeable'` tag, I only need the `my-content` tag ...

Can someone help me ?

I also accept other nodejs templating libraries suggestions that does work like this one (if this solves my problem)...

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you are using `my-content` as an attribute.

You need to use the `id` attribute, and change it to `<p id="my-content">` for bind() to work.

e.g.

```
var Plates = require("plates")

var html    = '<h1>Template test with plates</h1>'
            + '<p id="my-content">This should be erased...</p>';

var data = { 'my-content': "It is: "+new Date() };

console.log(Plates.bind(html, data));
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, but in my 3rd code sample, I'm using `my-content` as an attribute with a value (and it's working fine in that case)... And I need to use the attribute (without an attributed value) to template my HTML.... Isn't there a solution using "Plates" or maybe would there be a similar template engine that would allow me to template my HTML based on valueless html attributes ?